# Why are point clouds useful for large datasets of geometries?

Tags: computational-geometry, computer-vision, graphics, computer-graphics

In my computer graphics course I came across this "pro" for point clouds:

- Useful for large datasets (>> 1 point / pixel)

I'm trying to wrap my head about it, I know drawing is expensive, but, it somehow counterintutive to me that for larger datasets having to store more points is more efficient?
Why wouldn't it hold for smaller datasets (this would actually make sense to me...)?

Thank you for explanations you can provide, preferably simple!

Comment: What has been the context? Besides storage, there is, well, perceptibility: If you set every pixel corresponding to at least one point, expect almost every pixel set in a bilevel raster. With pixels set for *point cloud*s, you may be able to actually see something.

Comment: @greybeard thanks a lot. Really no context, just a bullet point in a pros and cons list on a slide under point clouds, we went through a lot of different ways (implicit and explicit) to represent geometry.  Perceptibility makes sense. How does storage factor in here? Would something like polygon meshes need less storage? Or implicit equations?